# Installing packages on multiple Centos machines

Tags: shell, centos, permissions, software-installation

I have to install standard package like java 1.7 in 40 of my lab machines which are connected over a LAN.

I know I can simply write a shell script to install something in user space of each system, that basically does an `scp` to each system and extracts them to user space, but how can I install packages from one sytem to another that requires root access to each system?

And yes I have root access to each of the system, but I don't know how to automate the installation over the network by controlling from a single system.

Answer (score 1):

first you need to automate login using ssh keys then write a script to run the install command in a loop 
You will also need to use one system which will be able to login to all other systems

First `cd` to your home directory to create ssh keys

```
cd
mkdir -p .ssh
cd .ssh
```

create keys and copy them to all other systems

```
ssh-keygen
```

copy the public key to remote machines

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@remotesys1
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@remotesys2
...
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@remotesys40
```

if you don't have DNS for remotesys1 then you can use IP

create a file with all the system name or IP in a file `systems.txt`

```
remotesys1
remotesys2
..
remotesys40
```

run the below script and change "./install.sh" to whatever you install command is

```
for system in $(cat systems.txt ) ; do echo $system ; ssh $system "./install.sh" ; done
```

Comment: you can improve on Abey's answer by using cssh instead